# About the "Never Accept an Ultimatum rule"

Tags: management, people-management

I've seen this mantra being spelled out around TheWorkplace:

> > As a manager, never accept an ultimatum

[The easy question] : Why is this a rule?

[The hard question]: Are there known, usually acceptable exceptions to this rule?

Comment: There are always exceptions to the rule, but I think its more of a case by case things rather than a list of conditions you could classify. It would also depend on the type of ultimatum offered up to you and a variety of other factors.

Comment: I can't tell what the question is because you didn't provide enough context.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about employees threatening to leave, do you specifically mean salary? I can think of a lot of situations where an employee would say "I will leave unless ..." where the manager for sure should accommodate (e.g. workplace safety). Even on salary, I would not say there is a hard rule.

Comment: You should [edit] this to make it more coherent because as it stands this reads more like a post that belongs on [meta].

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Neither. Just seen the saying around and thought it deserved scrutiny.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there known, usually acceptable exceptions to this rule?

Yes, any time you have no choice in terms of getting the work done. You can deal with it later.

Answer (score -1):

> Why is this a rule?

Never heard of this as a general rule and it seems stupid. Maybe you are missing a context here?

> Are there known, usually acceptable exceptions to this rule?

Depends on "acceptable". If you like jail time for example, not accepting ultimatums from the tax authorities could be your thing. If you don't need customers, not accepting deadlines might work. But for most normal businesses, they need to accept and work with ultimatums all the time.

Comment: How is "Pay your taxes until X, or else we will do Y" not an [Ultimatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimatum)?